# Using Bullet3 Pyhsics Simulator with VR and Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtual-reality, bullet, pybullet

This question concerns the [Bullet3 Physics engine](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3).

I'm trying to add VR capabilities to existing project that was written with pybullet in Ubuntu. The existing project has a complex set of dependencies that I'm not able to port to Windows so I need the bullet physics server to run on Ubuntu. In addition, as the project expands it'll likely be easier to develop in the Ubuntu environment as compared to Windows. I also understand that VR isn't really supported on Ubuntu, according to the bullet README.

With that in mind, I'd like to be able to run physics server on the Ubuntu side with an open TCP or UDP port, and then connect to that server from a Windows machine with VR capabilities. Both machines are on the same local network (and actually could be the same physical machine if using the Ubuntu subsystem for windows). I'm new to bullet and pybullet so I've been exploring the provided tutorials and pybullet quickstart guide, but though VR seems to be a well supported feature I haven't found any attempt to use VR in the way I've described above.

So far I'm able to start a physics server on the Ubuntu side but I haven't figured out a way to connect to it from the Windows side using VR. I was able to connect in the opposite way, with the server on the Windows side and the (non-VR) client on the Ubuntu side, but that isn't really what I was looking to do.

My question is: is setting up a bullet server on an Ubuntu machine and interacting with that server on a Windows machine using VR possible? From what I've read so far there doesn't seem to be any reason that it wouldn't be possible but I have yet to figure out a way to make it work. Maybe I'm just missing something though. I ask because this seems (to me at least) like the easiest way to use VR, given a widespread preference for Ubuntu servers and the fact that VR is only really supported on windows, so I'm surprised that there don't really seem to be any resources on setting up an environment like this.

Thanks!